# Error con autocompletar en Angular, valores se duplican

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-material

Estoy intentando usar el autocompletar de material angular, pero al momento de dejarlos dentro de un *ngFor para que sea dinamico (necesito crear una lista de items) el valor de lo ultimo que escribi en cualquiera de ellos se duplica,

Codigo con el problema
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2zfmf?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con la solucion
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En tu codigo estas utilizando el mismo `FormControl` para todos los items que se vayan agregando (siempre se usa el valor de `myControl`). Por eso se copia en los nuevos. Debes utilizar un nuevo `FormControl` para cada nuevo item.

Una solucion puede ser:

En el componente:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {

// Convertimos myControls en un array para tener nuevos FormControl`s 
  myControls: FormControl[] = [new FormControl('')];
// varios = ['hola']; Ya no se necesita
  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

// Tambien convertimos los filtros en array para tener filtros separados por cada control
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions.push(this.myControls[0].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filter(val))
      )
    );
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
  }


  agregarNuevo() {
    const nuevaPos = this.myControls.push(new FormControl(""));
    this.filteredOptions.push(this.myControls[nuevaPos - 1].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filter(val))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

En tu plantilla:

```
  <form class="example-form">

  <!-- myControls es un array de controles, usamos el index para saber cual filtro vamos a usar -->
  <div *ngFor="let control of myControls; let index = index">
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControls[index]" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">

         <!-- Usamos el index para seleccionar el filtro respectivo -->
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions[index] | async" [value]="option">
           {{ option }}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
     </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</form>


<button mat-raised-button (click)="agregarNuevo()">Agregar Otro Input</button>
```

[Aquí está el código funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2zfmf-myt7a7)

Una solución más elegante sería crear un componente para contener el formulario y el filtro. En el componente principal se harian copias por cada item. Sería más simple, pero te muestro como hacerlo a la manera que estabas intentando.

Comment: Si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto tu problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.